# Недопонимание с const

Tags: c, указатели, const

Допустим, я создаю в main() массив указателей, под которые позже выделяю память и инициализирую посредством функции fgets().

```
int main(void){    
    char *p[5];
    ............
   /* инициализация */
}
```

Затем я хочу отсортировать данный массив указателей и вызываю функцию sorting(). Для того, чтобы случайно не изменить данные в массиве указателей, аргумент функции sorting я сделаю const, тобишь:

```
void sorting(const char **p){
/* функция сортировки указателей */
}
```

Однако при вызове данной функции из main(), я получаю ошибку

```
int main(void){
.............
.............
sorting(p); 

}
```

предупреждение:

> passing argument 1 of ‘sorting’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      sorting(p);
>   expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
>   void sorting(const char **p){

Насколько мне известно, то const значения можно инициализировать НЕ const значениями, но это я читал для просто указателей. Скажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Объявите _const char *p[5]_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ваше желание вполне понятно и естественно, но тем не менее в С не разрешено неявное приведение типа от `char **` к `const char **`. На первый взгляд вам кажется, что вы просто запрещаете модификацию строк, но вместе с этим вы открываете другую "дыру" в защите константой корректности: если бы это было возможно, то внутри вашей функции `sorting` вы могли бы спокойно сделать, например

```
 p[0] = <адрес какого-то константного объекта типа char>;

 // Например:
 // static const char s[] = "Hello World!";
 // p[0] = s;
```

что привело бы к тому, что `p[0]` в `main` (имеющее тип `char *`) стало бы указывать на константный объект. И вы этого добились бы без применения явного приведения типа (!).

Вот для того, чтобы не открывать такой дыры в защите, С не разрешает неявных преобразований `T ** -> const T **`.

Красивого решения тут навскидку не придумаешь... В `main` вам, допустим, нужен именно `char *[]`, а в `sorting` вы, допустим, хотите получать именно `const char *[]`. В такой ограниченной ситуации остается только применить явное приведение типа.

Чтобы не замусоривать код явными приведенями можно, если вам не претит такая практика, спрятать его в макро

```
#define sorting(p) sorting((const char **) (p))
```